# Can I simplify the following code for qt?

Tags: c++, string, qt

I need to simplify validations on `qlineedit`, which invokes a function that returns a capital letter when I'm typing. I have this:

```
void dg_cliente::on_lineEdit_4_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{

    Cls_Validaciones *Valido = new Cls_Validaciones;

    ui->lineEdit_4->setText(Valido->Validar_Mayuscula(arg1));

}
```

The code is the very similar for `lineEdit5`, `lineEdit6`, `lineEdit7`, etc., which is redundant. Is there a better way to do this that removes the redundancy?

Comment: are you familiar with the `QValidator` class?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question as:

> How can I recognize which widget is an actual signal sender?

By calling [sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) function in your slot.

```
void DlgClient::onLineEditTextChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QLineEdit* pLineEditSender = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>( sender() );
    if (pLineEditSender) // also verify that is required type of sender
    {
       // FYI: setText also signals textChanged
       // make sure the code is not looping here
       // so bool m_forcedSetText initially set false

       if ( ! m_forcedSetText)
       {
          m_forcedSetText = true;
          pLineEditSender->setText(  myTransform(arg1) );
       }
       else
          m_forcedSetText = false;
    }
}
```

P.S. Maybe the other type of solution as suggested in comments is better? But the answer is explicit to what you ask. The info on [sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) does warn that the OOP principle of modularity is violated etc. while in certain cases the function is still useful.