# Not capturing keyboard shortcut keys in QT event filter (that forces text to upper case)

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt 5.6, I set up an event filter to force text entered by the user in QLineEdits and QTextEdits to upper case.
Context menu functions (copy, paste) work but the keyboard shortcuts do not.

Seems that I also capture control-shifted letters (ctrl-C, ctrl-V, etc.).

What am I not doing to exclude the control-shifted keys so that they get processed normally?

Code snippet below.

```
bool Form::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() >= Qt::Key_A && keyEvent->key() <= Qt::Key_Z &&
            ((keyEvent->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) == false))
        {
             QApplication::sendEvent(obj, new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress,
                keyEvent->key(), keyEvent->modifiers() | Qt::ShiftModifier,
                keyEvent->text().toUpper()));
            QApplication::sendEvent(obj, new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease,
                keyEvent->key(), keyEvent->modifiers() | Qt::ShiftModifier,
                keyEvent->text().toUpper()));
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My code makes the UI program not not capturing keyboard shortcut keys because of QT event filter
>   (that forces text to upper case). Why?

Mind that there is `Qt::ControlModifier` flag to enforce the filter:

```
(keyEvent->modifiers() & (Qt::ShiftModifier | Qt::ControlModifier)) == false
```

Also in your code sample I suspect calling parent class event filter will help solving the problem by preventing other unwanted effects:

```
// for all other cases, let it process then
return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, e);
```

But I would use designated `keyPressEvent` overloaded function:

```
void MyWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) override
{
    // filtering keypress modifiers as well
    // use your own key codes here
    if ((e->key() == Qt::Key_Z)  && 
       ! e->modifiers() & (Qt::ShiftModifier | Qt::ControlModifier))
    {
        // just an example to handle 'Z' pressed
        // with no control modifiers

        e->accept(); // set as 'handled here'
        return;
    }
    e->ignore(); // set as 'not handled here' 
}
```

And not the answer to your question but a similar solution can be done: [Can I simplify the following code for qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706152/can-i-simplify-the-following-code-for-qt/36706518#36706518)
I consider the latter better because no sending keys through the event loop involved. *And maybe using text edit validator even better solution but I have doubts. Nothing is new: such [solution](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18688-How-could-I-make-the-QLineEdit-UpperCase-without-using-InputMask) but for different question asked as well.*